# Fall through condition on a DynamicContent Control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a dynamicContent control I want to trap the error if there is no xp:key= matching value. I'm looking for something like a fall though that I can do something and not get a crash. I know that I can define a default key but I want to catch it at the end not the beginning. Or even something like dynamicContent.containsKey or dynamicContent.keyValues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xe:dynamicContent` has a `getFacet("facetId")` method. It returns a `UIComponent` or (assumably) `null` if the facet doesn't exist. Maybe you can use that to check if the facet exists.

Comment: Thanks Mark - that could work. I have sort of worked around the issue with the rendered property of the dynamicContent. getFacet might be a bit clearer process.